# Export data from Oracle Lite 10gR1 odb file

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I hope you can help me with this one. Years ago (2005) someone way before me set up a server with WinXP and a custom-written Java/Tomcat-whatever application for monitoring some sensors, the database backend apparently being Oracle Lite 10g (10.0.0.0.0). It has run flawlessly ever since the original setup...

Now, we have the problem that a disk failure (no backups, corrupted FS) rendered the Windows unbootable and I'd like to get that content out of the DB and importing it into MySQL or at least something that's readable by anything modern. We don't have any documentation and no one knows who did the setup.

The problem is that Oracle Lite apparently requires a "full" Oracle server as a "synchronization master", and no one here ever has worked with Oracle before or has any experience with that stuff (we're all Linux+(PHP/Python)+MySQL now).

How do we get out the contents of the database using a fresh WinXP or Win7 setup?

The connection code bits of interest in the Java source are (I hope I got all relevant):

```
Class.forName("oracle.lite.poljdbc.POLJDBCDriver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:polite:system/DBNAME:DBNAME;DataDirectory=C:\\mobileclient\\oldb40\\DBNAME;Database=DBNAME;PWD=PASS", "fm", "PASS");
```

Comment: did you have any luck with this?